# Multi-label classification with Caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, lmdb, pycaffe

I want to fine-tune GoogLeNet to do Multi-label classification with Caffe. I have already fine-tuned it to a single-label classification, but I can't make the transition to Multi-label yet.

The main steps I am doing which are different:

## Create LMDB for Data & Ground Truth

I am modifying the code [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1698#issuecomment-70211045) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/caffe-users/lmdb$20python/caffe-users/-vWuaM3bnro/RB4xzpI8xeUJ) to create one LMDB with the Data and the other with ground truth.

## Replacing SoftmaxWithLoss with SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss

Updating the train_val.prototxt, I replace SoftmaxWithLoss layers to SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss, and set the data layers so that both DB's are loaded. I set the learning rate parameters as I have done with the single-label classification problem.

This steps seems to be working. The data flow, and it is possible to perform solver.step(1). To verify the data and labels are loaded right, I have explicitly calculated the loss using the formula, and got the same result as Caffe.

## Problem

The network does not converge. Running it several hundrads of iterations, each of the different classes averages around the class population. That is if class a has 0.35 1's and 0.65 0's in the population, the network will converge to ~0.35 classification probability for each observation, regardless of the true label.

## Possible error 1

I suspect the problem is because I fail to load the images correctly into caffe in a way that GoogLeNet pretrained model can learn from them. My previous experience so far is convert_imageset which works perfectly. Right now I am using shelhamer code to save the images into the LMDB:

```
im = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(data_dir,in_)))
im = im[:,:,::-1]
im = im.transpose((2,0,1))
im_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(im)
in_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx), im_dat.SerializeToString())
```

I normalize the mean in the data layer when loading the image.
Does that seem right? Is there another way to do that?

## Possible error 2

It might also be that the train_val.prototxt has been defined wrong. Is there any thing else that need to be done than switching the SoftmaxWithLoss -> SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: it seems like your net get stuck with an "all 1" prediction. It might happen if your gradients are too high driving the parameters into meaningless regions. Can you plot a graph of training loss vs iteration number? I would try reducing learning rate by one or two *orders of magnitude* and re-train, see if the model is stuck again.

Comment: If your network is not converging, you should check the learning rate. Generally for fine tuning, you should have a lower learning rate (or a high learning rate to begin with and a rapid decay). If the train loss is increasing over epochs, it is an indication that your learning rate is too high.

Comment: Have you seen this issue?
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2407

Answer (score 0):

In GoogLeNet input data should be subtracted by mean:

```
...
im = im.transpose((2,0,1))
mean = np.array((104,117,123))
im -= mean
im_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(im)
...
```